# Fetch channel id using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot that will send the channel id in response to a command. For example, if I type the command `$channel` the bot will return the channel id of the channel where I sent the command.

I have the following so far (the command prefix is already set to '$'):

```
client.command(name = 'channel')
    async def channel(ctx):
       await ctx.send(#not sure how to return channel id)
```

It feels like there's a simple solution to this but I have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple:

```py
@client.command(name = 'channel')
async def channel(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.channel.id)
```

`ctx` stores many information - the user who used the command, server, channel, etc. ([check all](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context)). After getting the `channel` object you can get the `id`.